# Simple OData Client 4.0: Add custom headers to internal batch requests

Tags: c#, odata

I'm trying to send multiple requests as a batch through the Simple OData Client 4.0. As I need custom headers for our internal routing server side, I add them in the `BeforeRequest` part of my client. This is done for the overall batch request as well, but the internal requests of the batch don't have these needed headers and it seems that there is no way on client side to add them to each internal request.

```
...

settings.BeforeRequest = (e) =>
{
    e.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=" + apiKey);
    e.Headers.Add("V", "1");
};

...

var batch = new ODataBatch(settings);
var resultingFonts = new List<FontDto>();

// Search for the font name, to lower makes it case insensitive.
foreach (string fontName in fontNames)
    batch += async c => resultingFonts.Add((await c.For<FontDto>("Fonts").Filter(" ... ").FindEntryAsync()));

batch.ExecuteAsync().Wait();
```

Is there any way to add my custom headers to the internal requests on client side? So that the custom headers are added to the batch request fine, but not on the internal requests.

Comment: having the same issue.Was this resolved?

Comment: @BlueClouds I used the Microsoft HttpClient in the end, building the requests myself and adding them to the batch. I didn't see a solution with the Simple Odata Client sadly.

Comment: @SvenMöhring Do you know if this still applies? I have noticed Simple.OData.Client has now .WithHeader(string, string)  and .WithHeaders(Dictionary<string, string>) methods but it seems they would set headers for for the whole batch not individual requests inside.

Comment: @SebastianWidz Sadly, I don't work with this code anymore and thus am unable to help you in any way, sorry.

Comment: I've spent the whole afternoon and evening to investigate. The problem still applies. See my answer below using hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your custom headers using the Client.UpdateRequestHeader() method.

```
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
client.UpdateRequestHeader(...);
var batch = new ODataBatch(client);
```

Comment: It's worth adding that this method is not included in the IODataClient interface, so to use it you have to be referencing the concrete ODataClient class.

Comment: Does it update the main header in batch request or individual inner requests headers?

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old but the problem is still valid.
As of today (End of 2023), Simple.OData.Client 6.0.1 does not support changing headers for inner operations inside batch requests.
We can use a nasty hack to replace the Content in HttpRequestMessage

```
        settings.BeforeRequest += delegate (HttpRequestMessage message)
        {                
            if (message.Content is not null
                && message.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("$batch")
            {
                var content = message.Content as StreamContent;
                if (content is not null)
                {                                        
                    string requestBody;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(content.ReadAsStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true))
                    {
                        reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                        requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    
                    var replacedContent = requestBody.Replace("patternToSearch", "patternToSearch"+"additionalHeadersTxt");
                    var requestContent = new StringContent(replacedContent, Encoding.UTF8, MULTIPART_MIXED);
                    message.Content = new StreamContent(requestContent.ReadAsStream());                    
                    foreach(var header in content.Headers)
                    {
                        message.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
                    }
                                        
                    content.Dispose();
                    content = null;
                }
            }
        }
```